# Pandas join with categorical indices

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I'm getting unexpected results with attempting to join Pandas `DataFrame` objects with categorical indices. Here is the minimum reproducible example (boiled down from my real-life use case):

```
shape_categories=['square', 'circle']
color_categories=['red', 'blue', 'green']

test_a = pd.DataFrame({
    'shape': pd.Categorical(['square', 'circle'], categories=shape_categories, ordered=True),
    'color': pd.Categorical(['red', 'blue'], categories=color_categories, ordered=True),
    'value_a': [1.0, 2.0]
})
test_a.set_index(['shape', 'color'], inplace=True)

test_b = pd.DataFrame({
    'shape': pd.Categorical(['square', 'square', 'circle', 'circle'], categories=shape_categories, ordered=True),
    'color': pd.Categorical(['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue'], categories=color_categories, ordered=True),
    'value_b': [10.0, np.nan, np.nan, 40.0]
})
test_b.set_index(['shape', 'color'], inplace=True)

test_a.join(test_b, how='left')
```

I expect

| shape | color | value_a | value_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| square | red | 1.0 | 10.0 |
| circle | blue | 2.0 | 40.0 |

but instead I get

| shape | color | value_a | value_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| square | red | 1.0 | 10.0 |
| circle | blue | 2.0 | NaN |

What am I missing? I've tried to be careful to keep the dtypes of the categorical variables exactly the same.

Comment: what version are you on? I am running on Pandas 1.3.1 and it works fine. I may be misunderstanding your post, so kindly share your expected output

Comment: Just edited above to be clearer about what I suspect. I'm using pandas v1.1.3. Upgrading now to see if that helps.

Comment: Ugh. Upgrading to 1.3.3 did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: For posterity, here is the bug report: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38502 Fixed in 1.3

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify all of the indices to merge on, otherwise pandas will only use the first one. So in your case:

```py
test_a.join(test_b, how='left', on = ['shape', 'color'])
```

should produce the expected result.

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like explicit specification of join indices is necessary in 1.1.3, but not in 1.3.3

Comment: For posterity, here is the bug report: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38502 Fixed in 1.3